# SOAP callouts: How to define Wrapper class to get node's text as well as the attribute?

Tags: apex, soap, wsdl2apex, callout

I want to use salesforce standard method WebServiceCallout.invoke() to send a request and parse the response.
In the response I have a structure like below:

```
<bag>
   <item item-id="item1">STRING_CONTENT</item>
   <item item-id="item2">STRING_CONTENT</item>
</bag>
```

How to construct the wrapper class in order to get both item-id and STRING_CONTENT values?
WSDL2Apex produced Wrapper like below but there is no field for content!

```
public class Item {
    public String item_id;

    private String[] item_id_att_info = new String[]{'item-id'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.myUri.com/model','false','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{};
}
```

I tried to add the content field for Item element myself (by analogy to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392616/what-are-the-parameters-for-the-salesforce-webservicecallout-invoke-method) but this is not working:

```
public class Item {
    public String item_id;
    public String content;

    private String[] item_id_att_info = new String[]{'item-id'};
    private String[] content_type_info = new String[]{null,'http://www.myUri.com/model',null,'1','1','false'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.myUri.com/model','false','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'content'};
}

public class Bag {
    public Item[] items;

    private String[] items_type_info = new String[]{'item','http://www.myUri.com/model',null,'0','-1','true'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.myUri.com/model','false','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'items'};
}
```

In the Bag wrapper I can define an array of string String[] items which gets the content, but in this case I'm losing the item-id.

Comment: Can you post the "Bag" class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is **not possible with WebServiceCallout.invoke() to parse both node's attribute and text**.

The only way out seems to manually build xml, fire http callout and parse response myself.

This is what [FuseIT tool](http://www.fuseit.com/products/fuseit-sfdc-explorer/) generated for me (including the warning line):

```
//Warning: Simple Content Types with Attributes are not supported by WebServiceCallout.invoke
public class Item {
    public String input;
    private String[] input_type_info = new String[]{'input','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','1','1','false'};
    public String item_id;
    public String[] item_id_att_info = new String[]{'item-id'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.myUri.com/model','true','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{};
}
```

The FuseIT tool can generate the code to build xml and parse it but for now I'll stick to the **workaround** with getting only the node's text like below.

```
public class Bag {
    public String[] items;

    private String[] items_type_info = new String[]{'tokens','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','string','0','-1','true'};
    private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.myUri.com/model','false','false'};
    private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'items'};
}
```

Similar question: [Problem with Wsdl2apex with <s:extension> and value FuseIT tool](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/84983/problem-with-wsdl2apex-with-sextension-and-value-fuseit-tool)